# How can I get symbols beside encoding

Tags: python, json, encoding

I have such input data:

> Car Bmw™

I`m doing dictionary with this value:

```
{'productName': u'Car Bmw\u2122'}
```

How I can get output with correct symbol? like here:

```
{'productName': u'Car Bmw™'}
```

Can json.dumps fix it if I need to make json from dictionary?

Comment: what do you mean by fix it?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think , maybe after dumping , json module will apply some encoding for dictionaries?

Comment: The output seems OK for me. With python3.

Comment: @user189 i`m using p2, with # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Comment: why do you need u'Car Bmw™' in your dict?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve, what is the output you want?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham what are You mean?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid its written in body {'productName': u'Car Bmw™'}

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean this but what about:

```
json.dumps({'productName': u'Car Bmw\u2122'}, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: dumps is provided on production, so i cant modify json.dumps arguments

Comment: @user3683587 what is the output you are getting from it? I am getting {"productName": "Car Bmw™"} even if I try to save it to file.